# Context lookup for EJB client returns $Proxy119 object instead of actual class object

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.0

I am simply invoking a EJB 3.0 like this in JBoss:

`MyEJB myEJB = (MyEJB) initialContext.lookup("");`

Now the lookup works fine. The object returned has the viewType,moduleName, beanName as expected. But it throws this exception:

`2015-04-10 18:49:08,266 ERROR [org.teiid.CONNECTOR] (Worker0_QueryProcessorQueue1128) Connector worker process failed for atomic-request=GfxN/Obks1QK.1.1.0: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy119 cannot be cast to com.MyEJB`

How do I cast it to the object that I intend to use?

Comment: Is `MyEJB` your EJB class or your business interface?  You must cast to the business interface class, not the EJB class (unless you're using the no-interface view of EJB 3.1).  The container must return a proxy rather than an actual bean instance or else it will be unable to manage transactions, security, interceptors, instance pooling, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the correct way to do that is this:

```
    StatelessEJBLocator<MyEjb> locator = new StatelessEJBLocator(
            MyEjb.class, APP_NAME, MODULE_NAME,
            MyEjbRemote.class.getSimpleName(), DISTINCT_NAME);

    MyEjb myEjb = org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClient.createProxy(locator);
```

Answer (score 1):

here's a sample example of code :

```
HelloLocalHome helloHome;
HelloLocal hello;

//In your main or init method, 

// 1. Retreive the Home Interface using a JNDI Lookup
// Retrieve the initial context for JNDI.       
// No properties needed when local
Context context = new InitialContext();

// Retrieve the home interface using a JNDI lookup using
// the java:comp/env bean environment variable        
// specified in web.xml
helloHome = (HelloLocalHome) context.lookup("java:comp/env/ejb/HelloBean");

//2. Narrow the returned object to be an HelloHome object.      
// Since the client is local, cast it to the correct object type.
//3. Create the local Hello bean instance, return the reference 
hello = (HelloLocal)helloHome.create();

//And the call will be as follows :
hello.sayHello("James Earl")
```